# How to get data including HTML from a Rich Text editor using script and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, rich-text-editor

I got a rich text box editor form online and i have added to my webpage.the image of the Rich Text box is attached here.
[image]

code on my html body is

```html
<div class="wysiwyg-editor" id="editor1">
                                
</div>
```

the script is

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function($){
 
 function showErrorAlert (reason, detail) {
  var msg='';
  if (reason==='unsupported-file-type') { msg = "Unsupported format " +detail; }
  else {
   //console.log("error uploading file", reason, detail);
  }
  $('<div class="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+ 
   '<strong>File upload error</strong> '+msg+' </div>').prependTo('#alerts');
 }

 //$('#editor1').ace_wysiwyg();//this will create the default editor will all buttons

 //but we want to change a few buttons colors for the third style
 $('#editor1').ace_wysiwyg({
  toolbar:
  [
   'font',
   null,
   'fontSize',
   null,
   {name:'bold', className:'btn-info'},
   {name:'italic', className:'btn-info'},
   {name:'strikethrough', className:'btn-info'},
   {name:'underline', className:'btn-info'},
   null,
   {name:'insertunorderedlist', className:'btn-success'},
   {name:'insertorderedlist', className:'btn-success'},
   {name:'outdent', className:'btn-purple'},
   {name:'indent', className:'btn-purple'},
   null,
   {name:'justifyleft', className:'btn-primary'},
   {name:'justifycenter', className:'btn-primary'},
   {name:'justifyright', className:'btn-primary'},
   {name:'justifyfull', className:'btn-inverse'},
   null,
   {name:'createLink', className:'btn-pink'},
   {name:'unlink', className:'btn-pink'},
   null,
   {name:'insertImage', className:'btn-success'},
   null,
   'foreColor',
   null,
   {name:'undo', className:'btn-grey'},
   {name:'redo', className:'btn-grey'}
  ],
  'wysiwyg': {
   fileUploadError: showErrorAlert
  }
 }).prev().addClass('wysiwyg-style1');

 
 /**
 //make the editor have all the available height
 $(window).on('resize.editor', function() {
  var offset = $('#editor1').parent().offset();
  var winHeight =  $(this).height();
  
  $('#editor1').css({'height':winHeight - offset.top - 10, 'max-height': 'none'});
 }).triggerHandler('resize.editor');
 */
 

 
 
 


 


 

 //RESIZE IMAGE
 
 //Add Image Resize Functionality to Chrome and Safari
 //webkit browsers don't have image resize functionality when content is editable
 //so let's add something using jQuery UI resizable
 //another option would be opening a dialog for user to enter dimensions.
 if ( typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined' && ace.vars['webkit'] ) {
  
  var lastResizableImg = null;
  function destroyResizable() {
   if(lastResizableImg == null) return;
   lastResizableImg.resizable( "destroy" );
   lastResizableImg.removeData('resizable');
   lastResizableImg = null;
  }

  var enableImageResize = function() {
   $('.wysiwyg-editor')
   .on('mousedown', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if( e.target instanceof HTMLImageElement ) {
     if( !target.data('resizable') ) {
      target.resizable({
       aspectRatio: e.target.width / e.target.height,
      });
      target.data('resizable', true);
      
      if( lastResizableImg != null ) {
       //disable previous resizable image
       lastResizableImg.resizable( "destroy" );
       lastResizableImg.removeData('resizable');
      }
      lastResizableImg = target;
     }
    }
   })
   .on('click', function(e) {
    if( lastResizableImg != null && !(e.target instanceof HTMLImageElement) ) {
     destroyResizable();
    }
   })
   .on('keydown', function() {
    destroyResizable();
   });
     }

  enableImageResize();

  /**
  //or we can load the jQuery UI dynamically only if needed
  if (typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined') enableImageResize();
  else {//load jQuery UI if not loaded
   //in Ace demo dist will be replaced by correct assets path
   $.getScript("assets/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    enableImageResize()
   });
  }
  */
 }


});
  </script>
```

How can I post the data which i am entering inside the rich text box. I want to get with it's HTML code for saving to database. Please help me. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#editor1').keyup(function() {
    $('#hiddenCode').val(parseMe($(this).html()));
    
    // Sample output, which enables you to see the effect
    // Besides, this decodes your HTML entities
    $('#output').html(
      $('#hiddenCode').html(
        $('#hiddenCode').val()
      ).text()
    );
  });

  $('#editor2').keyup(function() {
    $('#hiddenCode2').val(parseMe($(this).html()));
  });

  // This will encode your HTML input
  function parseMe(value) {
    return value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
  }
});
```

```css
/* layout only */

#editor1,
#editor2 {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wysiwyg-editor" id="editor1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="wysiwyg-editor" id="editor2" contenteditable="true"></div>

<textarea id="hiddenCode" name="htmlCode"></textarea>
<textarea id="hiddenCode2" name="htmlCode2"></textarea>

<!-- Sample output -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

To hide those textareas above, just put the `hidden` attribute

If you hit the submit button, you can freely get the data because of those textareas. You can access them with their `name` attrubites.

Comment: Thank you for your grate help. if am using two rich text box in one form then how to get those there to different fields on save page?

Comment: this is the js file i have linked to my project - bootstrap-wysiwyg.min.js

Comment: where i have to keep that function you mentioned below the form?

Comment: it is taking the values now but the value is taking without html. it  is not taking line breakers, bold, underline or anything like that. How can i get that html value?

Comment: on  your server-side, you should decode your HTML input

Comment: i have entered rashid in bold letters in first line and appstribes in second line. but the value getting is    rashid<div>appstribes</div>

Comment: I've put an output box to see the effect.